# What exactly happens with library(<package>) when I source an R file

Tags: r, namespaces, package

If I have a function `fun()` which requires another function, say, `select()` from some other package (in this case `dplyr`) saved in an R file *helpfile.r*  and I want to use this function `fun()` in another R file, I can simply source that function using `source()`

Now I noticed that when I use `library(dplyr)` in *helpfile.r* and I source that file in my main file, the package gets loaded, however, all functions that have conflicts with other functions from other packages get ommited. In my case: I had already loaded the package `MASS` which also has a `select()` function that was still "active" after I loaded `dplyr` in this way.

**Question**: *Why doesnt the package that is loaded later in the chain overwrite the function from an earlier package, when I load a package via `source()`?*

Answer (score 2):

Packages mask each other in the order they are loaded. `source()` is like executing the whole file with `CTRL+SHIFT+S` or `CTRL+A` followed by `CTRL+ENTER`.

I'd recommend you to make your *helpfile.r* more standalone by not loading the whole package but writing out the complete namespace eg `dyplr::select()`.

Comment: Actually, it would be preferable to build a package. The package infrastructure allows much better fine control regarding what is imported from package namespaces.

Comment: Fully agree Roland. However diving deeper and deeper into R for the saint of best performance makes you more and more a software engineer instead of being just data scientist. I'm a geographer and sometime need a helperfile.r for only one specific project (which also is a git repository). In that case I skip igniting an other (git) project... For this case actually a `source()` function would be cool building one file as mini package :-)

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need more than a DESCRIPTION and a NAMESPACE file in addition to your helperfile.r to have a functional package. (But of course, you should always document your code and with knitr you can write documentation easily.)

Answer (score 1):

As @Jeremy pointed out above, explicitly stating the namespaces of the functions is always the safer option and is a good practice if you want to make your code more robust. The downside for this is that it makes your code harder to read for humans.

Alternatively, if you were to use a lot of functions from conflicting packages and want to avoid typing complete namespaces, you could use the `box` [package](https://klmr.me/box/). With that you can attach the package library, but use local aliases easily for certain conflicting functions, e.g.

```
box::use(MASS[MASS_select = select, ...])
```

This code would replace the `library()` function call.